# extending the json schema with a new type that checks the file on disk

Tags: python, json, schema

I want to write a JSON schema.
It supports the basic types like `{integet, strings, etc}`

I would like to define a type `{file}`

And would like that it is automatically checked if the file exists pyhsically

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: you need to write a python code for this which ultimetly yield you the json you want

Comment: This is quite unclear. JSON Schemas are for validating JSON. But JSON does not have a "file" type.

Comment: what i meant is that the json i want to validate could have URIs, I would like a way to define those in Json and the python code that could actually check the pyhsical presence

Comment: u can use this  library https://github.com/keleshev/schema#using-schema-with-docopt

Answer (score 0):

```
from schema import Schema, And, Or, Use, SchemaError
import os

a = open('test2.txt', 'w+')
a.close()

def checkFileExists(fileName):
    if os.path.exists(fileName):
        return fileName
    return None

data = {
    'filepath': 'test.txt', # doesn't exist case
    'filepath1': 'test2.txt'
}

s = Schema({
    'filepath': Use(checkFileExists),  # doesn't exist case
    'filepath1': Use(checkFileExists)
})

try:
    validaData = s.validate(data)
    print(validaData)
except SchemaError as error:
    print(error)
```

You can try something like this. The schema will return file name if the path exists else will return None